Rmd- Apply crosstalk filters to ggiraph plot
I want to use a crosstalk (or other) filter on a (shared) data frame and update the ggiraph plot dynamically.
Any way to make it work in rmd (without shiny)?
data <- mtcars %>% 

  mutate(
    label= as.character(gear) )


     sh=SharedData$new(data, ~label)
      

        fs <- filter_select("letterFilter", "Filter", sh, group=~label, multiple=FALSE )
        
        
   
    
    p <- ggplot(sh)+aes(x=wt, y=mpg,
                    tooltip = label,
                    data_id = label)+
      geom_point_interactive(size = 3) + theme_minimal()

    
    
    girafe(ggobj = p)


Not sure ggiraph supports crosstalk - see https://github.com/davidgohel/ggiraph/issues/93 You can use plotly instead

here is a similar, but not the same question, I answered with a dynamic crosstalk plot without shiny. Could you use something like this?

I think the answer is that it's not going to be easy to get it to work with crosstalk.  I don't know if there are other ways to have shared data.
To work with crosstalk, a display needs to be an "htmlwidget", and it needs to be aware of crosstalk.  ggplot() doesn't produce an htmlwidget, it just produces an object which prints as a plot.  On the other hand, girafe() does produce an htmlwidget, which is why it can do interactive graphics.
However, as far as I can see, ggigraph has not been written to be aware of crosstalk, and it looks as though it would be more or less impossible to do it:  since ggplot() needs to produce p in your example, you'll need to have R running to produce the object that girafe() is going to display.
One ugly way to do that without Shiny or some other version of R running in the background is to produce versions of p from every possible filter result, and save them all, then have the filter select which one to display.  I don't know if it would be feasible to do that.
Edited to add:  @RichardTelford gave a comment pointing to https://github.com/davidgohel/ggiraph/issues/93 which has a technical explanation for why this isn't going to be implemented.
